# EF6 - Update() fails with Multiple SaveChangeAsync, but not multiple SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update

I am currently facing a situation I ain't sure to understand. For each repository I have a base and this is a part of it:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Context for the database
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly DataBaseContext DbContext;

    protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

    // ...

    public virtual T GetById(Guid id)
    {
        Requires.ArgumentNotNullAndNotDefault(id);
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        Requires.ArgumentNotNullAndNotDefault(id);
        return DbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    // ...

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // ...

    public void SaveChanges() => DbContext.SaveChanges();

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The thing which is weird is that, if I get 2 time an entity (CarEntity), let's say, in the same context, I `GetById()` two times and update 2 different values, and at every `Update()`, I `SaveChanges()`, it throws the following exception, but only for the Async logic:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Project.Model.CarEntity' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
>   state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the
>   graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities
>   are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>   this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
>   the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' as appropriate.

There is my controller:

```
[Route("set_car_color_and_licence_plate_color")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Car))]
[HttpPost]
public Task<IHttpActionResult> SetCarColorAndLicencePlate([FromBody] SetCarColorAndLicencePlateRequest setCarColorAndLicencePlateRequest)
{
    return TryExecuteTransactionalFuncAsync(async () =>
    {
        Guid authenticatedStaffMemberId = GetAuthenticatedStaffMemberId();
        await CarService.SetCarColorAsync(authenticatedStaffMemberId, setCarColorAndLicencePlateRequest.CarId, setCarColorAndLicencePlateRequest.CarColor);
        await CarService.SetLicencePlateColorAsync(authenticatedStaffMemberId, setCarColorAndLicencePlateRequest.CarId, setCarColorAndLicencePlateRequest.LicencePlateColor);

        return Ok();
    });
}
```

And my 2 methods from my service

```
public async Task SetColorAsync(Guid authenticatedStaffMemberId, Guid carId, Color color)
{
    CarEntity carToUpdate = await CarRepository.GetByIdAsync(carId);
    if (carToUpdate == null) throw new BusinessException($"Unknown user for the id : {carId}");

    carToUpdate.UpdatedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    carToUpdate.UpdatedBy = authenticatedStaffMemberId;
    carToUpdate.Color = color;
    UserRepository.Update(carToUpdate);
    await CarRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task SetLicencePlateColorAsync(Guid authenticatedStaffMemberId, Guid carId, Color licencePlateColor)
{
    CarEntity carToUpdate = await CarRepository.GetByIdAsync(carId);
    if (carToUpdate == null) throw new BusinessException($"Unknown user for the id : {carId}");

    carToUpdate.UpdatedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    carToUpdate.UpdatedBy = authenticatedStaffMemberId;
    carToUpdate.LicencePlateColor = licencePlateColor;
    UserRepository.Update(carToUpdate);
    await CarRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Of course, I could do it in only one method, but SetColor() and SetLicencePlateColor() can be called separately and I don't want to have to maintain 2 time the same code.

If you try this piece of code (by including it into a project) in order to reproduce the situation, you'll see that the second `Update()`is the one that throws the exception above.

---

Because I can't provide the full code of `TryExecuteTransactionalFuncAsync`logic, there is a light version of it

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TryExecuteTransactionalFuncAsync(Func<Task<IHttpActionResult>> apiTask)
{
    using (var transaction = new DatabaseTransaction(DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()))
    {
        var output = await apiTask.Invoke();
        transaction.Complete();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did find a workaround ! Thanks to https://www.itworld.com/article/2700950/development/a-generic-repository-for--net-entity-framework-6-with-async-operations.html

I just changed my `BaseRepository` to:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Context for the database
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly DataBaseContext DbContext;

    protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

    // ...

    public async Task<(T, int)> AddAsync(T entity, bool autoSaveChangesAsync = false)
    {
        Requires.ArgumentNotNullAndNotDefault(entity);

        GetDbContext().Set<T>().Add(entity);
        return (entity, await saveChangesAsync(autoSaveChangesAsync));
    }

    public async Task<(IEnumerable<T>, int)> AddAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities, bool autoSaveChangesAsync = false)
    {
        Requires.ArgumentNotNullAndNotDefault(entities);

        var addedEntities = new List<T>();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
            addedEntities.Add((await AddAsync(entity, false)).Item1);

        return (addedEntities, await saveChangesAsync(autoSaveChangesAsync));
    }

    public Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        Requires.ArgumentNotNullAndNotDefault(id);
        return DbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    // ...

    public async Task<(T, int)> UpdateAsync(T entity, int key, bool autoSaveChangesAsync = false)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return (null, 0);

        T existingEntity = await DbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(key);
        if (existingEntity != null)
        {
            DbContext.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            return (existingEntity, await saveChangesAsync(autoSaveChangesAsync));
        }

        return (existingEntity, 0); // Because 0 entity have been written into the database
    }

    // ...

    private async Task<int> saveChangesAsync(bool autoSaveChangesAsync)
    {
        if (autoSaveChangesAsync)
            return await SaveChangesAsync();
        else
            return 0; // Because 0 entity have been written into the database
    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => GetDbContext().SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

> For this base, my keys are `int`, but you can change it to `Guid`, it
>   depends on your implementation

I hope it helps :)